# MVC 4 : Passing of selected guests details form View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My View has list of guests (i got entire list) and on their arrival, I have to mark them as arrived.
I wait for 30 min and submit all details to servers by clicking on submit button.

i will submit, guest ID and arrived status to server

I donot know how to pass last of the active guests from View to server.

**My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GuestList(GuestListForModel collection)
    {
        var temp = collection;

        return View();
    }
```

**MyView**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GuestList", "Guest"))
     {
     @foreach (var saiList in Model.GuestArrivalInfoList)
                 { 
                    <li class="group">
                        <div class="IB left">
                            <img src="images/user-1.png" alt="" class="stdImg rds50" width="100" height="100" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="left brRgt nameAge">
                            <div class="group">
                                <a href="#">@saiList.FirstName @saiList.LastName</a>
                                <div class="age">@saiList.Age<span class="font9">yrs</span></div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>                   

               <footer class="group">
                <div class="sheet brRgt left">
                    <span class="font9 dblock">present</span>
                    <div>@Model.Present</div>
                </div>
                <div  class="sheet brRgt left">
                    <span class="font9 dblock">@Model.Absent</span>
                    <div>1</div>
                </div>
                <div  class="sheet brRgt left">
                    <span class="font9 dblock">Model.NoAttendance</span>
                     <div>1</div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" />              
            </footer>
```

**Model**

```
public class GuestListForModel 
    {
        public bool Status {get;set;}      // arrived or not arrived.
        public Int GuestID   {get;set;}    


    }
```

P.S : I could not get satisfactory answer from googling.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes that you will need to make:

Change the GuestList action to accept a collection:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GuestList(ICollection<GuestListForModel> collection)
{
    var temp = collection;

    //do your processing    

    return View();
}
```

Use a for loop to render the guest list

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.GuestArrivalInfoList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.GuestArrivalInfoList[i].GuestID)
}
```

Razor/ASP.NET will take care of both setting the correct id in the view model when rendered (e.g. `GuestID` would have an id of "`GuestArrivalInfoList[1].GuestID`"), and will also handle the model binding when hitting the action, making sure that the collection of fields are mapped into the collection.

I presume that there are missing / additional details in your view model and GuestListForModel that ensure that you have the correct data going back and forth (e.g. I don't see the GuestID in the view).